# Looking for assistance / guidance in removing browserio

Tags: malware, virus

My mac air has become infected with a browserio virus. I'm trying to remove it and it just keeps coming back.

I've used Sophos to scan / quarantine but it didn't find it. 
I've used Malwarebytes[https://www.malwarebytes.com/] to scan for malware as well.
I've used Piriform[https://www.piriform.com/] to try to uninstall it but it comes back with the message that says `close the program before uninstalling it`.
There is no close option, just a search text menu that shouldn't be there.
When I try to kill the process, it simply creates another one.

Any way to get rid of this thing?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the browserio app, If on your mac, look up by the clock/battery meter. There should be an icon of a magnifying glass. Quit that, drag the Websearch.app to the trash, empty the trash and done.

I hope this helps someone else.